# AES-256 Shift-Rows Offsets

Tags: aes

I am currently trying to implement a AES-256 cipher according to this sepcificaciton:
http://techheap.packetizer.com/cryptography/encryption/spec.v36.pdf

As well as on Wikipedia and in the document these offsets for the shift-rows operation are given (depending on the key size):

```
Row  128 192 256
 1    0   0   0
 2    1   1   1
 3    2   2   3
 4    3   3   4
```

The example for 256-Bit encryption (page 26 onwards) obivously uses the same offsets (0-1-2-3) for all key sizes:

```
R[ 1].s_row   d4bf5d30e0b452aeb84111f11e2798e5 (given Example)
R[ 1].s_row   d4bf52aee0b411f1b84198e51e275d30 (my calculation with 0-1-3-4)
```

Extracting the rows:

```
Row#  0-1-3-4 calculation  example calculation
 1    d4 e0 b8 1e          d4 e0 b8 1e
 2    bf b4 41 27          bf b4 41 27
 3    52 11 98 5d          5d 52 11 98
 4    ae f1 e5 30          30 ae f1 e5
```

So the question is: What are the correct offsets: 0-1-2-3 or 0-1-3-4? If the latter is correct (what i believe) there is an error in this document or i missed the up-to-date version since 2003 is already a while ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the document talks about Rijndael, not AES.

Aren't Rijndael and AES that same?  Well, not precisely; Rijndael is specified with a set of parameters that AES does not support; how example, how it works with different block sizes.  AES is defined only with a block size of 128; Rijndael supports a set of different block sizes.

That is where your confusing is coming from; the varient shift-rows are used if you have a block size of 256 bits; since AES never has a block size of 256, those shift rows are never used.